# Most elegant way to stop getting CS8602 in VS2022, .NET 6, C# 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I have the following sample code in VS 2022, C# .NET 6.0:

```
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root/>");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("aaa"))
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```

and am getting "CS8602: Dereference of a possibly null reference" at the doc.SelectNodes line. The code works in the sense that it does not fail but simply does nothing when it does not find a node named 'aaa'. If I put 'root', it finds it. So, as far as I see, I am doing nothing wrong and offending to the compiler.

Yet, the warning is there and seems wrong and therefore annoying. My two questions are:

1. Is it a bug in the compiler warning logic?
2. Is there a better (meaning, short, not superfluous) way to write similar code that searches for all nodes matching a certain XML query and to process them that does not generate the warning?

I found out that I can just add "#pragma warning disable CS8602", but that does not feel like a great solution. Ideally, I would like to take advantage of this warning in other cases that seem to me legitimate unlike this one.

Comment: `in doc.SelectNodes("aaa")!`? *Is it a bug in the compiler warning logic* - no, it's that `System.Xml`, being a very old namespace, was never decorated with the nullability attributes.

Comment: Are you certain the warning is on `doc.SelectNodes` and not `node.OuterXml`

Comment: Yes, it highlights doc.SelectNodes(), and it is not the "doc." part but the SelectNodes that is apparently delcared as returning XmlNodeList?

Answer (score 7):

If you are really sure, that a nullable value cannot be null in your code, use the null-forgiving operator https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving. See the minimum character change "!" in the code.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root/>");
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("aaa")!)
  Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```

Be sure that SelectNodes(...) really does not return NULL. Seems to be ok for your example - see
https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.Xml/System/Xml/Dom/XmlNode.cs,9d1bb97e7daa3b4e,references

Comment: This is the right answer

Answer (score 6):

**What is the most elegant way to stop getting the error?**
In your project file delete  `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>`

**Is it a bug in the compiler warning logic?**
No

**Is there a better (meaning, short, not superfluous) way to write similar code?**
"Better" is subjective. I think your code is fine, but this is what the warning wants you to do:

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.LoadXml("<root/>");
 var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("aaa");
 if (nodes == null)
 {
     //handle this case here
     return;
 }
 foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
     Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```

Or you could do something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<root/>");
foreach (var node in Enumerate(doc.SelectNodes("aaa")))
    Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```

```
private static IEnumerable<XmlNode> Enumerate(XmlNodeList? list)
{
    if (list == null) yield break;
    foreach (XmlNode item in list)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. All of these are helpful, as they help clarify for me certain nuances of the language and VS. I think I understand fully. I believe the issue is the discrepancy between the method definition of "public XmlNodeList? SelectNodes(string xpath)" and the fact that it will never return null. 

The shortest code results by switching the warnings off in the .proj.

Comment: In `doc?.SelectNodes("aaa");`, the `?` is unecessary: `doc` cannot be null there. The warning only concerns the fact that `SelectNodes` _can_ return null.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand that as *GSerg* commented, the API method being declared as XmlNodeList?(string) is the source of the warning (yet, it never returns null; it returns a non-null reference to an empty list).

My subjective "most elegant" solution that I found so far is to do this:

```
#pragma warning disable CS8602
foreach (XmlElement item in doc.SelectNodes("..."))
#pragma warning restore CS8602
```

because that suppresses just this instance, and I can benefit from other instances of this warning that, I dare say, are more legitimate.

Comment: Nigel's wrapper method is going to be the shortest and arguably most elegant solution that does not completely switch off the warning in all other instances if there are lots of cases of SelectNodes in the code.

My solution to disable / SelectNodes / enable seems ok if there are not that many cases. The question would be what is less ugly: the green warning line or the two pragmas.

Comment: `because that suppresses just this instance` - then why didn't you go [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654932/most-elegant-way-to-stop-getting-cs8602-in-vs2022-net-6-c-sharp-10/71656003#comment126637765_71654932) `doc.SelectNodes("aaa")!` that [exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) just for that?

Comment: Your question specifically states that you want to avoid `#pragma warning disable CS8602`